# Windows 10 C++ using Visualstudio code but wont let me file>new>project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, windows-10

So I am using Visual Studio Code on my Windows 10 laptop right now and using the book C++ Crash Course by no scratch press and it is asking me to install visual studio 17 but I have Visual studio code up to date next it is prompting me to " set up new project 1. select File>New>Project 2. In installed, click visual C++ and select general. select empty project......
so my question is do need Visual studio instead of visual studio code because it will only let me click  file and new file and the only out I have found for this is going through the command prompt but the book is telling me to go through Visual studio do I need both vs and vs code?
and I'm already using g++
please help and thank you

Comment: Vs code is just an editor. You need visual studio community 2017 in your case.

Comment: Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are two very different programs despite the similar names. Visual Studio also ships with its own C++ compiler, which is presumably what the book expects you to use

Comment: I agree with the other comments, you need Visual Studio to follow along with the book. The Community edition is free. I suggest getting the latest [2019 edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/). There may be some differences from the book, but they will be minor. The main difference is that 2019 has a new startup screen where you can click "Create a new project", or "Continue without code" to go right into the IDE which will be much like the 2017 version. Alternatively, you can get the [2017 edition here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/).

Comment: I should add that you can have _both_ Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 installed side by side. It's not an "upgrade" where one replaces the other; it's very common to have multiple Visual Studio versions installed together. So I would start with 2019 to have the latest and greatest, but you could always install 2017 too and have them both available.

Comment: Thank y'all,  I really do appreciate it. I w as smashing my head against the wall with this one.  Y'all  are awesome.